# What is causing my refrigerator to make an intermittent loud noise?

Tags: refrigerator

I've had a new refrigerator for a little over a year. In the past week or so, it's started making a noise that goes for approx 10 minutes, then stops for awhile, then starts again, and so on. When I open the fridge door, the sound quickly slows down and stops.

Any notion as to what's going wrong and how to address it?

Comment: What make and model is the fridge?

Comment: The model is LG LMXC23746S